# How do config that an SFTP user can access two root folders on different drives from OpenSSH Windows Server?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp, windows-server, sshd

SFTP user is a service account so we cannot create 2 separate service accounts per employee.

One service account is under group service 'Users' and 'Admin-Users' then it should be able to access the following 2 directories on different drives.

- C:\product
- D:\special-product

Below is sshd_config for OpenSSH Windows server.

```
Match Group "Users"
    ChrootDirectory C:\product
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Match Group "Admin-Users"
    ChrootDirectory D:\special-product
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Therefore, How do config that an SFTP user can access two root folders on different drives from OpenSSH Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, so maybe it's not possible across windows disk drives, but I would suggest putting a link to both paths in another root folder with [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)